# ENVELOPE_ALLOWANCE_EXCEEDED error on demo API call

Tags: docusignapi

I have a basic plan of docusign which gives me 5 envelop per month. I am testing my integration key on demo api before going live. It needs 20+ api test calls before upgrading demo integration key to live. But after 5 demo api calls it is giving me following error:

Exception: ENVELOPE_ALLOWANCE_EXCEEDED The envelope allowance for the account has been exceeded.

Can someone please help as I am new to docusign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo accounts should not have such a strict envelope limit. First, I would recommend confirming your calls we're actually hitting your Sandbox. To do so, log in to the demo environment: from https://developers.docusign.com/ click on Go to Sandbox. If you log in through that method, do you see the envelopes you created using your integration?

If so, your Sandbox may have been incorrectly provisioned. Please send an email to go-live@docusign.com with your Production account ID and your Demo account ID.